# Writing a long hash for a file converter

Tags: ruby

I've created a hash for a file converter. The file gets loaded into the program, and from there the file goes to a hex editor and the user picks and chooses what they want to do to the file. During the users' choices, the choices will run against a hash containing all hex information. It will then translate the hex and return it back to the file. The user will then use the another part of the program to resave the file with a new extension (still a work in progress).

I have a super long hash and was wondering if there's a better way to write the hash. I won't be posting the entire hash due to shear size of it.

```
hexadecimal_translate = { 
                        '00' => ["n", "u", "l"],
                        '01' => ["s", "o", "h"],
                        '02' => ["s", "t", "x"],                        
                        '03' => ["e", "t", "x"],
                        '04' => ["s", "e", "l"],
                        '05' => ["t", "a", "b"],
                        '06' => ["r", "n", "l"] ,
                        '07' => ["d", "e", "l"],
                        '08' => ["g", "e"], 
                        '09' => ["s", "p", "s"],
                        '10' => ["r", "p", "t"], 
                        '11' => vt,
                        '12' => ff,
                        '13' => cr,
                        '14' => so,
                        '15' => si, #<= All the way to 99 => r,
                        '0a' => rpt,
                        '0b' => vt,
                        '0c' => ff, 
                        '0d' => cr,
                        '0e' => so,
                        '0f' => si,
                        '1a' => ubs,
                        '1b' => cu1,
                        '1c' => ifs,
                        '1d' => igs, 
                        '1e' => irs, #This is by far the scariest number I've ever seen.
                        '1f' => itb # need to also make it able to support IUS
                        # all the way to 9f => which equals nothing btw
                        }
```

Comment: We could give you better advice if you also showed us how you use this hash in your code.

Comment: Actually, it may be helpful to post the entire hash...

Comment: Stub code is off-topic, and if this isn't stub code, I don't know what is :P

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I'm not trying to argue but how is this stub code?

Comment: @Ekult3k "*I won't be posting the entire hash...*" And even besides that, you're posting part of a definition of a hash. You don't show us the actual program – what if, for example, your code is better suited to a config file, or a dynamically-generated hash? We can't give good reviews if you post a clipped snipped. You also never say what "vt", "ff" etc. are, which makes it impossible to know if, say, there's code duplication that would help shorten the definition.

Comment: _A method stub or simply stub in software development is a piece of code used to stand in for some other programming functionality. A stub may simulate the behavior of existing code (such as a procedure on a remote machine) or be a temporary substitute for yet-to-be-developed code._ Also I say this is for a _Hex Editor_ at least three times. I'll give you one guess what "vt" means.

Comment: All I'm literally asking is, "_is there a shorter way to write a hash?_"  How in the world is that off topic? Not only that but I've given a clear definition of what this hash is used for, you don't need to know what the other half of the program looks like to answer a question on how to write a hash better, that doesn't make any sense. I'm not trying to be arrogant or anything, just trying to understand what is happening right now

Comment: @Ekult3k From [the first link in the close reason](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3652/62850): "*Excerpts of large projects are fine, but if you have omitted too much, then reviewers are left imagining how your program works.*" In this case, you didn't even include the entire hash, let alone enough of the program to give a good review. Note, by the way, that I said "you can't give a good review", not that you asked an unanswerable question. Good reviews of this code (which are, incidentally, what we strive for here at Code Review) require context that this lacks. Hence, stub code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby uses SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE for constants, which is what you are setting up, so  I would call the variable `HEX_MAP`. If you have a super long constant, and it's not created programmatically, then listing it a line at a time is clearest.

Ruby will coerce `00` into `0` unless you treat it as a string. You can use the shorthand for arrays. So, the first couple lines should be:

```
'00' => %w(n u l),
'01' => %w(s o h),
```

Comment: I know I'm going to change the variable here soon. I didn't know you could use `%w( )` in a hash, thank you.